# Java Prime Factorization: Program timing out?

Tags: java, timeout, factorization

Before I get blasted for not following the rules, I DID utilize the search function and see that there are multiple threads on this exact problem. However, none of them answered my specific question.

I'm working on Euler problem #3, where I need to find the highest prime factor of 600851475143. *I don't need help solving the problem.* I have made a brute force method (could be better, I know) for solving it.

The program returns correctly for all of the tests that I did with smaller numbers (7 digits and less). However, when I enter 600851475143 as a long input, my program never gives me a return. Is my number simply too big the be entered? What could be causing this to happen? I originally thought it was because I was using int tags instead of long, but changing those didn't alter my result.

I'm sure this is simple and I'm missing it, but I am very curious as to what's happening. Thank you in advance :)

```
//Euler 3: Largest Prime Factor
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;


public class Euler3 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a number!");
        // Create scanner
        long numberInput=scn.nextLong();
        //Can't have a factor higher than it's square root
        double limit=Math.floor(Math.sqrt(numberInput));
        // System.out.println(limit);

        //Start testing from the highest number possible
        for(long i=(numberInput-1);i>0; i--)
        {
            if(numberInput%i==0) 
                System.out.println(i+" is prime: "+isPrime(i));

        }

    } //End Main


    public static boolean isPrime(long n) 
    {
        //check if n is a multiple of 2
        if (n%2==0) return false;
        //if not, then just check the odds
        for(int i=3;i*i<=n;i+=2)
        {
            if(n%i==0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would revisit "I don't need help solving the problem. I have made a brute force method (could be better, I know) for solving it." - Many Project Euler (and code competition) problems are designed to be infeasible using brute-force implementations with bad bounds. Run the code with progressively larger values (from one that runs quick) and plot the times on a graph - what does it look like?

Answer (score 0):

To verify if a number is Prime or not, use the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), it will run much faster compared to your naive `isPrime` method. I won't provide any implementation hint due to this phrase: *I don't need help solving the problem*.

Also, there could be other hints that you missed. I recommend you to review the problem statement:

> What is the **largest** prime factor

Answer (score 0):

A `long` variable can [easily fit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) your desired value into it

> long: The long data type is a 64-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 and a maximum value of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (inclusive). Use this data type when you need a range of values wider than those provided by int.

The problem is that your algorithm is not an efficient one.  As has already been mentioned, use the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the `isPrime` method but in the loop you use to call it. You count down from your number `n` with increments of 1, and you call `isPrime` only for divisors of `n`: it will take `n/2` steps before you get to the first potential divisor of `n` - so, in the order of 10^12 steps for your example `n`.